# Reconnecting Emulator to Eclipse

Tags: android-emulator

My main problem with developing in Android is that the emulator seems to continually get disconnected from eclipse. This always happens the 2-3 time I try to upload my .apk from eclipse without rebooting the emulator. Eclipse indicates this with an empty DDMS ->Device section and logcat stays blank - sometimes I'm not sure if the new code made it on the device.

The only fix I have for this is to shut down eclipse, and restart it. With the restarting of Eclipse, on top of the emulator boot time, I can't get any momentum going in my development.

Is there a way to reconnect the emulator to eclipse without having to restart Eclipse or even the Emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "emulator" from console. That way it will stay on regardless of eclipse state.
 [starting emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#starting)

also, try using `adb devices` to find out is your emulator really running

Answer (score 0):

You can reconnect your emulator using the Android Debug Bridge (ADB).

There are 2 primary methods to do this:

1. In Eclipse, open the "Devices" view.  The last button on the right (upside down triangle) will open a menu of additional options.  The very bottom selection is "Reset adb"
2. From a command prompt you can type the following 2 commands to stop and restart ADB.
   adb kill-server
   adb start-server